# Combine multiple functions into one in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I made 3 functions to import data from a `.csv` file and then take a specific column to then sum the data within the column. I want to export all three `dataFrame`s from each respective function into **one** `.xlsx` file. If I run the functions one by one, they will overlap and only the last function will be exported to the `.xlsx` file. How do I export all three functions simultaneously so that the `.xlsx` file will have all three of the exports?
P.S this is my second week of python, this might be a very amateur-like question. thanks.

```
 import pandas as pd


def file1(file_name_one):
    importing = pd.read_csv(file_name_one)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Net Sales':[importing['Net Sales'].sum()]})
      df1.to_excel('excelfile.xlsx',
             index=False,
             header=False,
             startrow=5,
             startcol=3,
             )

def file2(file_name_two):
    importing2 = pd.read_csv(file_name_two)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Net Sales':[importing2['Net Sales'].sum()]})
      df2.to_excel('excelfile.xlsx',
             index=False,
             header=False,
             startrow=6,
             startcol=3,
             )

def file3(file_name_three):
    importing3 = pd.read_csv(file_name_three)
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Amount':[importing3['Amount'].sum()]})
      df3.to_excel('excelfile.xlsx',
             index=False,
             header=False,
             startrow=7,
             startcol=3,
             )

print(file1(r"example1.csv"))
print(file2(r"example2.csv"))
print(file3(r"example3.csv"))

#this will result only in the export of file3(), 
#the other 2 functions get "overlapped", how do I also export the other two functions?
```

Comment: What have you tried for yourself? Redefining the basic signature of the method to include a column as parameter would prob. be a good start already.

Comment: The method signature is the combination of the method name and its parameters. So go from something like "def your_new_method(file1, file2, file3)".

Comment: Is that how to combine the 3 functions into just one function? could you explain further?

Comment: That would be a way to combine indeed. It's basic python. Perhaps just check how functions work first (https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/functions-python-tutorial)

Comment: I'm quite familiar with the materials contained in the link you attached, but how can I apply "def your_new_method(file1, file2, file3)", into my script? much thanks.

Comment: Look at what changes from function to function ("Net Sales" instead of "Amount", `importing` instead of `importing2`, etc.) Any hard-coded value like this should be replaced with an additional function parameter, so that the correct value is specified by the *caller*.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, you want the 3 data frames to be stored in the same excel file.

The issue with your code is you're over-writing the data in the same sheet. Instead you can save each dataframe in its won sheet like this:

```py
df1.to_excel('excelfile.xlsx', sheet_name='df1' ...

df1.to_excel('excelfile.xlsx', sheet_name='df1' ...

df3.to_excel('excelfile.xlsx', sheet_name='df3' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So in theory:

```
def handle_files(file_net1, file_net2, file_amount):
    net1 = pd.read_csv(file_net1)
    net2 = pd.read_csv(file_net2)
    amount = pd.read_csv(file_amount)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Net Sales':[net1['Net Sales'].sum()]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Net Sales':[net2['Net Sales'].sum()]})
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Amount':[amount['Amount'].sum()]})
    df1.to_excel('excelfile.xlsx',
             sheet=NetResult1
             index=False,
             header=False,
             startrow=7,
             startcol=3,
             )
    df2.to_excel('excelfile.xlsx',
             sheet=NetResult2
             index=False,
             header=False,
             startrow=7,
             startcol=3,
             )
    df3.to_excel('excelfile.xlsx',
             sheet=Amount
             index=False,
             header=False,
             startrow=7,
             startcol=3,
             )
```

Should do the trick right?

Ow and the call should be:

```
handle_files(example1.csv, example2.csv, example3.csv)
```

BTW: I included @Gangula's anwers in here as well, with the different sheets.